# How to make Solr not to differentiate between 'John' and 'JOHN'

Tags: solr

in solr i have to get the uniqque values in my 'name' field of my database.

for that reason I read about grouping and I get the desired result

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":16,
    "params":{
      "indent":"true",
      "q":"name:И*",
      "group.field":"name",
      "group":"true",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "grouped":{
    "name":{
      "matches":2231,
      "groups":[{
          "groupValue":"ИВАН",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1144,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "obshtina":"ПЛОВДИВ",
                "phone":"032/670309",
                "timestamp":"2013-03-04T08:43:53.553Z"}]
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"ИЛИЯ",
          "doclist":{"numFound":177,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "obshtina":"БРЕЗОВО",
                "phone":"(3191)2265",
                ..............................
```

The problem is that now i noticed that unfortunately I've got 2 groups which are actually the same 'Иван' and 'ИВАН' . and the problem is that my 'name' field should be of type string so i can use wildcard character which I need  so i can't make it text for example and use LowerCase filter

Comment: Could you index two fields (using copyfield) and make one case insensitive using LowerCase filter?

Comment: I didn't want to do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [KeywordTokenizerFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory) (which does absolutely no Tokenization, just like string field) along with [LowerCaseFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory) to get what you want.

You will still be able to perform wildcard searches.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the previous answer you can use a new Solr text type as below, At index time just store the value as a single token in lowercase. While searching just consider the search text as a single token in lowercase. You can thus get the desired effect.

```
      <fieldType name="lcase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
     <analyzer type="index">
             <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
             <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
         </analyzer>
         <analyzer  type="query">
             <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
             <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
         </analyzer>
      </fieldType>
```